# Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have this recursive look up to get the list of territories a Sales Rep belongs to - the problem is I'm running into the "too much CPU time" governor limit.  Any suggestions on how to re-write it so that it doesn't do that?

```
public List<string> getHeirarchy() {
    List<Territory> territories = [SELECT Id, Custom_External_TerritoryId__c, ExternalParentTerritoryId__c FROM Territory];
    return getParentAndChildren(getTerritory(), territories);
}

public Set<string> getChildren(string parent, List<Territory> territories) {
    Set<string> subset = new Set<string>();
    for(Territory t : territories) {
       if (t.ExternalParentTerritoryId__c == 'US-'+parent) {
           subset.add(t.Custom_External_TerritoryId__c.SUBSTRING(3));
       }
    }

    return subset;
}

public List<string> getParentAndChildren(string parent, List<Territory> territories) {
    Set<string> collection = new Set<string>();

    Set<string> children = getChildren(parent, territories);
    if(children.size() > 0) {
        for(string child : children) {
            collection.addAll(getParentAndChildren(child, territories));
        }
    }
    collection.add(parent);

    List<string> sorted = new List<string>(collection);
    //sorted.sort();
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: If you are viewing a User's territories, then you should use [`UserTerritory`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_objects_userterritory.htm) instead. It represents a User who has been assigned to a Territory.

Comment: You should be able to query `[select TerritoryId from UserTerritory where UserId = :userId and IsActive = true]` and store that in a set.  Then query your Territory object with `where Id in :territoryIds` to get at your custom external field.

Comment: Hi Scott, that would indeed get me the current territories for the user but I'm also interested in the sub groups in case this is a manager.